# SAS Import excel file from networking drive

Tags: sas

Before code look like a below

```
datafile="&glb_path.\01_projects\P010_date_MART\tests.xlsx"
 sheet="RCDTCOD";
getnames=yes;
mixed=yes;
usedate=yes;
scantime=yes;
run;
```

The following code selects a file from my oracle server, I would like to change to open from network drives.
at this location "\CORP.AD.GS.COM\DFS"

```
proc import out=polisy2
           datafile='\\CORP.AD.GS.COM\DFS\\01_projects\P010_date_MART\tests.xlsx'
```

I dont know how to do it and which i run above code i got error ERROR: Physical file does not exist

Comment: Show the error message.  Most likely the path you are trying to read does not exist on the machine where you are running the code.

Comment: `DFS\\01_projects` typo could be the ERROR.  If not, in your windows login try mapping a drive to the network share and using that.